# How do I completely uninstall Virtualbox from macOS?

Tags: virtualbox, macos

I want to know how to uninstall virtual box correctly. I tried removing it from /Applications, but lots of things were left behind. I don’t want to use an app cleaner tool and would like a complete uninstall process if possible.

How can I remove the app and reverse the changes it makes when installed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct method to uninstall Virtualbox is to use the official uninstall script that is included on the installation image.  If you don't have the installation image anymore, you can re-download it. Since the program installs many helper scripts outside the /Applications folder, you need to clean those up with the included uninstall tool and not just trash the main app.

This information is available directly from the project page as well:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#install-mac-uninstall

[image: Screenshot of Virtualbox image mounted on Mac]

Comment: Thanks the stars we can run a nice script and not have to mess with PsExec and RegEdit. https://superuser.com/a/1258517/76395

Comment: I prefer using Homebrew Cask to install GUI apps if available. Running `brew cask uninstall virtualbox` runs the same VirtualBox_Uninstall.tool script, without the hassle of keeping around the install DMG.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew  is now using this format: `brew <command> --cask` So the correct command will be `brew uninstall --cask virtualbox`

Comment: The post does not say anything about installation via Homebrew. Why do u assume that?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/325680)

Comment: It was supposed to be a comment to @Nimesh Neema's suggestion not answer to the question