# How to uninstall VirtualBox / removing Kernel Extension

Tags: catalina, virtualbox, macos

Reading this [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367372/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-virtualbox-from-macos)

I made with brew: 
`brew cask uninstall virtualbox`

`Error: Cask 'virtualbox' is not installed.`

The `dmg` file of virtual box is not on disk..

Thanks for any good ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can either redownload the virtual box `dmg` and run that script or download and run [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/GWuzRrZ9) script

The script above is just the script I got from the `uninstall.tool`

Comment: success - stuff (including plist) deleted

Comment: @Juergen Does that mean it successfully uninstalled?

Comment: yes - good hint